# Richtiger Genitiv von Fußverkehr(s)schutzanlagen

Tags: genitive, proper-noun, gender-neutrality

Im Rahmen von genderneutraler Sprache würde ich gerne beim Wort 'Fußgängerschutzanlage' Fußgänger mit Fußverkehr ersetzen. Nun bin ich mir nicht sicher, ob es Fußverkehr**ss**chutzanlage oder Fußverkehr**s**chutzanlage heißen muss.

Liege ich richtig, dass hier ein Genitiv-s angehängt werden muss, da es sich um eine Zusammenziehung des Ausdrucks 'Anlage zum Schutz des Fußverkehrs' handelt?

Da es sich um einen recht fachsprachlichen Begriff handelt, kann ich hierzu nicht wirklich etwas finden (Für die meisten ists ja einfach ne Ampel...).

Comment: Wenn "Fußgängerschutzanlage" mangels Gender-Neutralität ersetzt werden soll, warum dann nicht den perfekt gender-neutralen Begriff aus der Alltagssprache "Ampel" in die Fachsprache integrieren?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Ampel ist auch ein Containerbegriff, da steckt viel hinter, was fachsprachlich ausdifferenziert werden muss (es gibt FSA, LSA, BÜSTRA,... - alles Ampeln)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt zum [Fugen-S](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut), um das es sich da handelt, [keine klaren Regeln](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-bratskartoffeln-und-spiegelsei-a-293186.html), nur ein paar [Daumenregeln](https://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/zwiebelfisch/der-gebrauch-des-fugen-s-im-ueberblick/).

Dass es sich um etwas sehr ähnliches, aber nicht dasselbe wie einen Genitiv handelt, sieht man an Beispielen wie *Liebesbrief* oder *Armutszeugnis*. Was sollten "Liebes" und "Armuts" für Genitive sein?

Ich würde mich hier an anderen Wörtern mit "Verkehr" orientieren wie *Verkehrsschild, Verkehrsampel, Verkehrsrecht, Verkehrspolizei*, und deshalb auch zu *Verkehrsschutz* mit Fugen-S tendieren. Mir fällt spontan keine Zusammensetzung mit *Verkehr...* ohne den Fugenlaut ein.

Wenn jemand den *Gewehrschuss* anführt, gehen mir aber auch die Argumente aus.

Der Kern ist, dass man sich beim Fugen-S über die Frage "Genitiv oder nicht Genitiv" wenig Gedanken zu machen braucht, denn das bringt nicht unbedingt weiter.

Comment: Daumenregeln (rule of thumb)? Ich kenne im Deutschen nur Faustregeln.

Comment: @infinitezero https://www.dwds.de/wb/Daumenregel https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Daumenregel . "Übern Daumen gepeilt" für geschätzt und "Pi mal Daumen" kennst du sicher auch.

Comment: Letzteren beiden kenne ich, für Daumenregel wird tatsächlich aber eine mögliche Herkunft als Lehnübersetzung angegeben :)